# Flask-WTF: variable choices for SelectField in FieldList of FormField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a setup with a `FieldList(FormField(SubForm))` where `SubForm` includes a `SelectField` whose choices are determined at runtime (in the view function). Currently I have the following setup, which basically derives a new class for `SubForm` with the choices each time it is called:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, url_for
from wtforms import SelectField, StringField, FieldList, FormField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm as Form

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_key'

class BaseForm(Form):
    @classmethod
    def append_field(cls, name, field):
        setattr(cls, name, field)
        return cls

class SubForm(BaseForm):
    title = StringField('SubForm')

class RootForm(BaseForm):
    entries = FieldList(FormField(SubForm))

@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form_viewer():
    form = RootForm(title='Title')
    subformclass = SubForm
    subformclass = subformclass.append_field('options',
                    SelectField('Options', choices=[('%i' %i,'option%i' %i) for i in range(1,5)]))

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        while form.entries:
            subform = form.entries.pop_entry()
            print(subform.options.data)
    else:
        print(form.errors)

    for entry in range(1,3):
        subform = subformclass()
        subform.title = 'SubTitle%i' %entry
        form.entries.append_entry(subform)

    html_template = '''<html>
            <form action="{{ url_for('form_viewer') }}" method=post>
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ form.entries() }}
            <input type=submit value=Submit>
            </form>
            </html>'''

    return render_template_string(html_template, form=form)
```

My problem is now, that if the app restarts (because things happen) between a GET and POST request, then it raises `AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'data'` while trying to access the submitted form data.

How can this be fixed? Or is there maybe another, better way to have a variable number of `SelectField`s with variable choices?

**edit:**

I think the problem was, that after `FieldList` was created, I changed `SubForm`.  So now I am creating `FieldList` in a similar way 
like `SelectField`:

```
formclass = RootForm.append_field('entries', FieldList(FormField(subformclass)))
```

But I am still wondering whether this is the way I am supposed to do it? It feels like, there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: What you could do is run some code on the app startup that would check for the existence of this 'UnboundField' object and if it's not initialized, you could create it. This way, you would make sure that even if the app restarts between a GET and a POST, this error would not happen.

Comment: @Jean-MichelProvencher Not really what I did now, but your comment lead me in the right direction.